# Unable to understand how data frames work in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I came across the solution of a coursera programming assignment problem in R. The problem is to write a function 'complete' in R. The function ‘complete’ reads a directory full of files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. The function should return a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases.

I came across the following solution:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){
    ## 'director' is a character vector of length 1 indicating
    ## the location of the CSV files
    
    ## 'id' is an integer vector indicating the monitor ID numbers
    ## to be used
    
    ## Return a data frame of the from:
    ## id nobs
    ## 1  117
    ## 2  1041
    ## ...
    ## where 'id' is the monitor ID number and 'nobs' is the
    ## number of complete cases
    results <- data.frame(id=numeric(0), nobs=numeric(0))
    for(monitor in id){
        path <- paste(getwd(), "/", directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", monitor), ".csv", sep = "")
        monitor_data <- read.csv(path)
        interested_data <- monitor_data[(!is.na(monitor_data$sulfate)), ]
        interested_data <- interested_data[(!is.na(interested_data$nitrate)), ]
        nobs <- nrow(interested_data)
        results <- rbind(results, data.frame(id=monitor, nobs=nobs))
    }
    results
}
```

I am unable to understand what interested_data is and what is being assigned to it in the two lines that begin with interested_data?

Comment: `interested_data` is simply the data frame that contains non-missing values for both `sulfate` variable and `nitrate` variable. If you were interested in finding rows that contain no missing values, which is how I might interpret the question, one can simply use `sum(rowSums(!is.na(monitor_data)) == ncol(monitor_data))`

Comment: The two lines you mention create a data dframe that is a filtered version of `monitor_data`.  The first line filters out those rows that do not contain missing values in the `sulkfate` column, the second then filters out those remaining rows that have missing data in the `nitrate` column.  As an aside, I would say that whilst the code may be a *working* solution to the question, it is not a *good* solution, for at least two reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the intended use for stack overflow and you would be better served following some new user guides for R in general, but to point you in the direction this is the sort of approach you can use:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){

    results <- data.frame(id=numeric(0), nobs=numeric(0))
    for(monitor in id){
        path <- paste(getwd(), "/", directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", monitor), ".csv", sep = "")
        monitor_data <- read.csv(path)
        interested_data <- monitor_data[(!is.na(monitor_data$sulfate)), ]
        interested_data <- interested_data[(!is.na(interested_data$nitrate)), ]
        nobs <- nrow(interested_data)
        results <- rbind(results, data.frame(id=monitor, nobs=nobs))
    }
    results
}
```

You want to know what `interested_data` is.
The first mention of `interested_data` is this:

```
interested_data <- monitor_data[(!is.na(monitor_data$sulfate)), ]
```

Which can be read as "assign to the name `interested_data` a copy of the object `monitor_data`, but only those rows in which the variable `sulfate` is not `na`."

Working backwards, what's `monitor_data`?:

```
monitor_data <- read.csv(path)
```

It turns out `monitor_data` is the result of calling the function `read.csv()` on a file, the location of which is indicated by the variable `path`.

To learn about `read.csv()` enter the following in your R console:

```
?read.csv
```